# alphabetize array algorithm

Tags: php, sorting

I wrote an alphabetical sort algorithm that for the most part works, but always leaves errors in element order. I can't figure out whats wrong.. Can you? Heres the code:

```
$sorted_users=array();
$sorted_users[0]=$users[0];
while(count($users)>0){
    $_i=0;
    $i=0;
    while($i<count($sorted_users)){
        if(strcmp(strtolower($sorted_users[$i]['last_name']),strtolower($users[0]['last_name']))>0){
            $_i=$i;
            break;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    array_splice($sorted_users,$_i,0,$users[0]);
    array_splice($users,0,1);
}
```

Comment: `usort($users, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['last_name'], $b['last_name']); });`

Comment: That works way better